# No AdMobs displayed on 2.3 but displayed with Android 4+ with Google Play Services

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I was trying to update an old project I had that used AdMobs SDK 6.x and was build in Eclipse. I updated to Google Play Services V29 and it worked fine on a tablet running Jelly Bean, my phone running Marshmallow. However when I run it on two old phones I have running Gingerbread (one is 2.3.4 the other 2.3.7) no ads show.

In LogCat, I get the following errors when the ad should be displayed:

> This app is using a lightweight version of the Google Mobile Ads SDK that requires the latest Google Play services to be installed, but Google Play services is either missing or out of date.

I even created a new projects in Android Studio, selecting Google AdMobs Ads Activity which works fine on my Marshmallow phone and the tablet, but on the Gingerbread phones I also get the same error

The version of Google Play Services on both phones are 9.0.82 (034-121907432)

Is there something I need to change so that the ads are loaded and displayed on GingerBread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This same issue has been bothering me for a few days now. From what I can tell, this is an issue with Google Play Services 9.0.82 running on Gingerbread devices. If I uninstall Google Play Services, ads show without issue.

When I reinstall Google Play Services, ads disappear and the "lightweight version of the Google Mobile Ads SDK" message in logcat reappears. Furthermore, within about a minute, I would get a message saying Google Play Services has crashed.

I'm not sure if there is anything that can be done from a developer standpoint except wait until Google Play Services is updated. I have posted a question to the Admob Google Group about this.

Comment: Linking to your(?)  Admob Google Group posting [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/Xur52sC6YTM)

Answer (score 0):

by **Vu Chau 

Mobile Ads SDK Team**

> *This is actually a known bug, for which we have a fix slated for release.  Right now the fix will crash on devices that run on an out-of-date Google Play services version, or those that don't have a Play services APK installed locally.
>   The fix is a server-side change, so once it has rolled into production, the issue should be gradually alleviated.*

[source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/Xur52sC6YTM/v3QBbm-7AgAJ)